# Rails simple js not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My application.html.erb has a simple script to set time out for 3 sec and in the mean time a gif is to be displayed .But the code is not working .Also the gif is working fine if elsewise used in the document.

Can someone tell what am I doing wrong here.

```
   ##application.html.erb
    <script>function hideLoading() {
        $("#loading").hide();

    }

    function showLoading() {
              $("#loading").show();
           }

    function dosomething() {
        showLoading();
        setTimeout("hideLoading()", 3000);
        return false;
    }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="loading">
        <img src="/assets/loading2.gif" alt="loading" />
    </div>

    <%= yield %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're defining but never calling `dosomething()`, so it never gets executed (unless you have not posted the code where it is called). In any case you can put a random `alert('foo');` into the `dosomething()` function to check if it is being run.

If you're using jquery this would be an appropriate way to call `dosomething()` as soon as the DOM is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dosomething();
});
```